# How to permanently configure the CPU performance setting on SLES?

Tags: systemd, cpu, sles

We are doing a:

vi /etc/systemd/system/cpupower.service

```
[Unit]
Description=CPU powersave

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/cpupower idle-set -D 0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/cpupower frequency-set -g performance

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and:

```
chmod 644 /etc/systemd/system/cpupower.service; systemctl enable cpupower.service
```

on SLES12.3 machines, but after reboot this doesn't sets them!

It will only get set if we do a "systemctl restart cpupower.service" **manually**..

**The Question**: how to make it permanent, so it will be set after every reboot?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i.$(date +%F-%Hh-%Mm-%Ss) 's/#governor/governor/g; s/#energy_perf_bias/energy_perf_bias/g; s/#min_perf_pct/min_perf_pct/g' /usr/lib/tuned/*/tuned.conf
```

tuned helped! (off: it should be modified in /etc/, not in /usr, since a tuned update could remove the setting)